# C++ setting char pointer to null

Tags: c++, pointers, nullptr

In Visual studio 2012, I was messing around with pointers, and I realized that this program kept crashing:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main ()
{
   const char* pointer = nullptr;

   cout << "This is the value of pointer " << pointer << "." << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

My intent was the set a `pointer` to `nullptr`, and then print the address. Even though the program compiles, it crashes during runtime. Can someone explain what is going on?

Also, what's the difference between `pointer` and `*pointer`?

Comment: @jogojapan And a duplicate of A LOT of questions out there.

Answer (score 8):

You are using a `const char*` which, when used in `std::cout`'s `operator <<`, is interpreted as a string.

Cast it to `void*` to see the pointer's value (the address it contains):

```
cout << "This the value of pointer   " << (void*)pointer << "." << endl;
```

Or if you want to be pedantic:

```
cout << "This the value of pointer   " << static_cast<void*>(pointer) << "." << endl;
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5e95969e2cf0d0e351365834b7efc3df-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba)

Comment: awesome, thank you so much!
is there a way to print out the memory location without having to typecast pointer?

Comment: `static_cast<void *>(pointer)` would be more elegant.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec And pedantic. :)

Comment: There is nothing elegant about `static_cast<void*>(pointer)`, it is the correct way though

Answer (score 1):

Although you can do `cout << "Pointer is " << (void*)pointer << ".\n";` as already been suggested I feel that in this case the "C way" of doing it is prettier (no casting) and more readable: `printf("Pointer is %p\n",pointer);`

Comment: Formally, that would also require a cast, since the `%p` conversion requires a `void*`. In C, `char*` and `void*` are however required to have the same representation, and I'm almost sure that is so also in C++, so, formal incorrectness notwithstanding, no sensible implementation can do something unexpected when getting a `char*` for the `%p` conversion [for values of "sensible" that don't include intentional punishment of people omitting the cast]. It could "honestly" break for pointers to other types than character types, since those need not have the same representation.